# When forming the local ring of an algebraic curve, why consider only restrictions of rational functions from the affine plane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In differential geometry, an "extrinsic" approach is taken (using an atlas of charts e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition)).  If an analogous approach was taken to defining rational functions on an algebraic plane curve, would more functions be obtained? Put another way: when forming the local ring of a plane curve at a point, why are only restrictions of rational functions from the affine plane considered?

Comment: There is a complex manifold (holomorphic) structure on (smooth) complex curves, unfortunately it doesn't generalize well to other fields. Note how hard it is to imagine interesting functions on subvarieties of $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p^n$, other than rational functions.

Comment: Thanks - but (to clarify) I am interested in why the only rational functions considered are restrictions of those from the affine plane (instead of rational functions defined extrinsically - would that give us more functions?).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: There are not more functions. Of course, first you have to define your atlas of charts...